# equals() method for classes with bidirectional association

Tags: java, equals, bidirectional

I am trying to implement `equals` method for Java classes `Book` and `Chapter` in my application. `Book` has a set of `Chapter`s, while a `Chapter` has an associated `Book`. The bidirectional association is shown as below:

```
class Book{
    private String isbn;
    private String name;
    private Date publishDate;
    private Set<Chapter> chapters;
    ...

    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(o == this){
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Book)){
            return false;
        }
        Book book = (Book)o;
        if( (this.isbn.equals(book.getIsbn()) ) && (this.name.equals(book.getName())) &&(this.publishDate.equals(book.getPublishDate())) &&(this.chapters.equals(book.getChapters())) ){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Now I tried to implement `equals` for `Chapter`:

```
public class Chapter {
    private String title;
    private Integer noOfPages;
    private Book book;
    ...

    public boolean equals(Object o){
         if(o == this){
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof Chapter)){
            return false;
        }
        Chapter ch = (Chapter)o;
        if((this.title.equals(book.getTitle())) && (this.noOfPages.intValue()== book.getNoOfPages().intValue())  ){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Here, I am wondering if I need to compare the book field as well. Wouldn't that start an infinite loop? What is the correct way of implementing the `equals` method for such bidirectional associations?

Answer (score 4):

A book should be equal to another book only if their ISBNs are equal. So implement the book equals only based on that field.

For the chapter - compare the chapter number and the owning `Book`

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming this is Java)
In the Chapter class equals method, you could just compare the book references (that is, using ==, not equals). This only compare references, so it would avoid an infinite loop. However, if you Clone books sometimes, this approach would fail.

An even better way to solve this specific case would be to compare not the books, but their ISBN, since that is an unique identifier for a Book.

In general, it is better to avoid bidirectional dependencies like this. One way is to have one of the two classes implement an interface, so as not to use it directly.

Comment: Even if using interfaces prevents the bidirectional dependency between the classes, there is still a bidirectional dependency between the instances at runtime. So I suggest that one should not compare the books (either by `==` or `equals()`), but either simply ignore the books (are two identical chapter from different books really equal or different?), or compare a book identifier like the ISBN.

Comment: I agree completely, I just commented on the circular dependency since I was taught to avoid them whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

From a modeling perspective, the chapter is part of the book. So although you have references in both directions, the book is "stronger" than the chapter.

When you have part-of relationships like with Book and Chapter, the part (Chapter) sometimes takes the whole (Book) into account when defining equals(). But not the other way round.

So clearly, the book would not use its chapters to define equals(). The chapter might use the book. That depends on the model.

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose a `Book` field as a ID (like ISBN). Then, in `Chapter` equals, you can do a thing like

```
book.getISBN().equals(other.book.getISBN())
```